# How to elimate names which start with "." when files are listed

Tags: c, substring, c-strings

I am trying to mimic the ls -l command via c program
But unfortunately didn't get how to ignore files like
"." , ".." and ".filename" but not filename.c
I managed to find . in the filename and ignore, but later realized that i lost even **filename.c**

Acuatual contents were

```
.
..
.bitfile
.gnupg
krishna
program.c
temp
```

Now my code is

```
while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strstr(dir->d_name, ".") != NULL || strstr(dir->d_name, "..") != NULL)
                continue; 
            strcpy(array[i], dir->d_name);
            i++;
        }
```

The contents in arrays were:

```
krishna
temp
```

But expected output was

```
krishna
program.c
temp
```

Comment: `if(dir->d_name[0] == '.') continue;` In your cases you can test that the string *began* with that substring with `if (strstr(dir->d_name, ".") == dir->d_name)`

Comment: Note that what Weather Vane [and P.J.] suggested is correct. Although less compact, what you wanted for your code was _not_ `strstr` but `strcmp`. You need to compare against `0` and _not_ `NULL` (e.g.): `strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") == 0` You may want to look at the `-a` and `-A` options of `ls` because they change whether `.` files are displayed or not.

Comment: @CraigEstey how will it work with `.filename`?

Comment: @CraigEstey you can do it some pervert way like `strncmp(dir->d_name, ".",1)`. But it rather ridiculous way of checking the single character.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland I wasn't advocating the `strcmp` over the `[0] == '.'` approach, merely that OP wanted `strcmp` for his/her approach. Normally, we'd want the `strcmp` [or `if ((d_name[0] == '.') && ((d_name[1] == '.') || (d_name[1] == 0)))`] to catch `.` and `..` The tricky part is that we want to emulate `ls` and skip files that begin with `.` [even `.foo`], so that simplifies the test.

Comment: @CraigEstey How are you going to use `strcmp` to skip ".filename". I am just waiting for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do not simply:

`if (dir->d_name[0] == '.') continue;`

Comment: this is plain wrong. many files in linux start with . and are hidden.

Comment: @WalterM, the fact that their filename starts with a dot _is_ what makes them hidden. That is just a convention though, there is nothing special about these files. So yes, the answer is fully correct as it is in effect what `ls` will do also.

Comment: Nope. ".. . and hidden files are not the the same. check out -A flag.

Comment: @WalterM it does not matter as OP wants to skip any file && directory with `'.'` at there beginning. So what is *`plain wrong`* here?